# angularjs empties array before populating with data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, angularjs

I am trying to find a way to minimize jsonp requests as angular does not cache these. My approach is to set the empty arrays I had in each controller into a main controller that loads once as it is attached to body. After that I will just check if the array is empty and if it is then use the service and return the json. 
My problem now is that for some reason that I do not understand the array is empty when checked outside of the service call.

example code

```
angular.module('Feed.controllers', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope)
  {
    function getYear()
    {
      var currentDate = new Date();
      return currentDate.getFullYear();
    }
    $scope.currentYear = getYear();
    $scope.StandingsList = [];

  })
  .controller('StandingsCtrl', function($scope, APIservice, $routeParams)
  {
    console.log($scope.StandingsList.length); // returns 0

    if ($scope.StandingsList.length === 0)
    {
      APIservice.getSomtehing().success(function (response)
      {
          $scope.StandingsList = response.jsonData;
          console.log($scope.StandingsList.length); // returns total entries
      });
    };

    console.log($scope.StandingsList.length); // returns 0

  })
```

MainCtrl is in body tag as I am using the currentYear to various places in HTML
StandingsCtrl is called using routes and partials for presentation. The div with the ng-view is inside the body element of MainCtrl

Comment: don't do that local caching in a controller, do that in a service.... and the reason why the array is empty is because every controller instantiates new `$scope`, so you are not pointing to the same variable

Comment: hmm if I am not pointing to same variable, then why if I delete the variable from MainCtrl I get Error: $scope.StandingsList is undefined, which is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'deleting' variable, but two controllers don't share any `scope` variables, only when those are `rootScope` variables, both controllers will inherit them, as all `scopes` are descendants of the `rootScope`

Comment: I mean if I delete the line $scope.StandingsList = []; in MainCtrl, then I get the undefined error which means that StandingsCtrl uses StandingsList from MainCtrl. Am I wrong?

Comment: can you create a fiddle? it's hard to tell what's going on when I see only definition but not the usage in html

Comment: Hmm I am not sure how to implement everything in fiddle with the partials etc, but I can give you the github url if it helps
https://github.com/PixelVibe/F1/tree/master/src

Answer (score 2):

the `$scope` of MainCtrl is not the same `$scope` as in StandingsCtrl, you might want to do something like this to share data between controllers

```
angular.module('Feed.controllers', [])
    .factory('Standings', function() {
        var list = [];
        return {
            save: function(data) { /*push data into list*/ },
            list: list
        }
    })
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Standings) {
        function getYear() {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            return currentDate.getFullYear();
        }

        $scope.currentYear = getYear();
        $scope.StandingsList = Standings.list;
    })
    .controller('StandingsCtrl', function ($scope, APIservice, Standings) {
        console.log(Standings.list.length); // returns 0

        if (Standings.list.length === 0) {
            APIservice.getSomething().success(function (response) {
                Standings.save(response.jsonData);
                $scope.StandingsList = response.jsonData;
            });
        }

    });
```